# Contraction of a second-rank tensor with the metric tensor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

Is it legitimate to perform the following tensor contraction?

$ g_{\alpha\beta} G_{\mu\nu}  \partial^\mu \phi \partial^\nu \phi = g_{\mu\nu} \delta^\mu_\alpha \delta^\nu_\beta G_{\mu\nu}  \partial^\mu \phi \partial^\nu \phi = g_{\mu\nu} G_{\alpha\beta}  \partial^\mu \phi \partial^\nu \phi $

Comment: The rules are indices may only appear twice on each side of the equals sign. That is you have too many $\mu$'s and $\nu$'s which makes it ambiguous.

Comment: Hello LeeMortacci and welcome to Physics SE. It could prove to be quite beneficial if you were to provide some more information on your problem. You could for example describe your terminology and what each symbol represents. Even more, saying a couple of things on the context or background of your question can help people here a lot to answer your question and/or provide guidance.

Comment: @ZaellixA thanks for the reply. I was reading a paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1310.3753.pdf) in which dark matter and gravity are non-minimally coupled. This yields to a modified Einstein field equation (EFE), with the non-minimal coupling yielding to an effective stress-energy tensor (SET). The term I'm showing above appears in this effective SET, and sees the Einstein tensor and derivatives of the dark matter (real) scalar field contracted together. I was wondering if I could somehow 'decontract' the Einstein tensor and group it with the Einstein tensor on the left-hand-side of the EFE.

Comment: @LeeMortacci you should include all that information into your question. This will hopefyully help people to help you :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not. When working with Einstein notation, you should never use the same index more than twice on an expression, or it will lead you to inconsistencies.

It is perfectly fine to rewrite the metric as $g_{\alpha\beta} = g_{\sigma\rho}\delta^{\sigma}{}_{\alpha}\delta^{\rho}{}_{\beta}$, this is not an issue. However, you can't use the same indices you were using on the other bit of the expression. The procedure, when written with explicit summations, reads like this
$$
\begin{align}
g_{\alpha\beta} G_{\mu\nu}\partial^{\mu}\phi\partial^{\nu}\phi &= \sum_{\mu,\nu} 
g_{\alpha\beta} G_{\mu\nu}\partial^{\mu}\phi\partial^{\nu}\phi, \\
&= \sum_{\rho,\sigma} \sum_{\mu,\nu} 
g_{\sigma\rho}\delta^{\sigma}{}_{\alpha}\delta^{\rho}{}_{\beta} G_{\mu\nu}\partial^{\mu}\phi\partial^{\nu}\phi.
\end{align}
$$

Notice the introduction of new summation symbols. The reason this manipulation is allowed is because $\sum_{\sigma} \delta^{\sigma}{}_{\alpha}$ "selects" the $\alpha$ entry and keeps the expression unchanged. If we used the expression you wrote, notice we'd get
\begin{align}
g_{\mu\nu} \delta^{\mu}{}_{\alpha}\delta^{\nu}{}_{\beta} G_{\mu\nu}\partial^{\mu}\phi\partial^{\nu}\phi &= \sum_{\mu,\nu} 
g_{\alpha\beta} G_{\mu\nu}\partial^{\mu}\phi\partial^{\nu}\phi, \\
&= \sum_{\mu,\nu} 
g_{\mu\nu} \delta^{\mu}{}_{\alpha}\delta^{\nu}{}_{\beta} G_{\mu\nu}\partial^{\mu}\phi\partial^{\nu}\phi, \\
&= \sum_{\mu} 
g_{\mu\beta} \delta^{\mu}{}_{\alpha} G_{\mu\beta}\partial^{\mu}\phi\partial^{\beta}\phi, \\
&= \sum_{\mu} 
g_{\alpha\beta} G_{\alpha\beta}\partial^{\alpha}\phi\partial^{\beta}\phi \tag{no summation over repeated indices},
\end{align}
which is vastly different from your original expression.

Comment: Very clear, thanks for dissipating my basic doubt!